# Add two lines from csv file to array(s)

Tags: c#

I have a csv file with the following data:

500000,0.005,6000

690000,0.003,5200

I need to add each line as a separate array. So 50000, 0.005, 6000 would be array1. How would I do this?

Currently my code adds each column into one element.

For example data[0] is showing 500000
                                   690000

```
static void ReadFromFile(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
            // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                string line;
                // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
                // the file is reached.
                while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    string[] data = line.Split(',');
                    Console.WriteLine(data[0] + " " + data[1]);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Let the user know what went wrong.
            Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You have not shown us how you populate mortgage array

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, do you want a 2d array? Or 1d array with items separated with a space?

Comment: where is _mortgage_ array, because _data_ array is just fine

Comment: sorry that was a typo, it was meant as data[0]

Comment: Does `string[][] results = File.ReadAllLines(filePath).Select(x => x.Split(',')).ToArray();` work for you?

Comment: `Currently my code adds each column into one element.` so..... is that what you want or not?? Please be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Using the limited data set you've provided...

```
const string test = @"500000,0.005,6000
690000,0.003,5200";

var result = test.Split('\n')
                 .Select(x=> x.Split(',')
                              .Select(y => Convert.ToDecimal(y))
                              .ToArray()
                        )
                 .ToArray();

foreach (var element in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{element[0]}, {element[1]}, {element[2]}");
}
```

[image]

---

Can it be done without LINQ? Yes, but it's messy...

```
const string test = @"500000,0.005,6000
690000,0.003,5200";

List<decimal[]> resultList = new List<decimal[]>();

string[] lines = test.Split('\n');

foreach (var line in lines)
{
    List<decimal> decimalValueList =  new List<decimal>();
    string[] splitValuesByComma = line.Split(',');

    foreach (string value in splitValuesByComma)
    {
        decimal convertedValue = Convert.ToDecimal(value);
        decimalValueList.Add(convertedValue);
    }

    decimal[] decimalValueArray = decimalValueList.ToArray();

    resultList.Add(decimalValueArray);
}

decimal[][] resultArray = resultList.ToArray();
```

That will give the exact same output as what I've done with the first example

Comment: Where is the array created or initialized in this? Is there a way to do this without using System.Linq;?

Comment: also it seems to be the same problem where both lines are added to the same array...

Comment: what do you mean by both lines being added to the same array

Comment: Each line is in its own array, so `line 1` is in `array 1`, `line 2` is in `array 2`, those arrays are then stored in another array used as a container. So parent array has the values `[array1, array2]`, `array1` contains values `[500000,0.005,6000]`. while `array2` contains `[690000,0.003,520]`... so essenitally what you have is `[[500000,0.005,6000],[690000,0.003,5200]]` there is no array here that contains `[500000,0.005,6000,690000,0.003,5200]`.

Comment: @AydinAdn i think he means the 'parent' array is 'the same' but that is exactly what OP wanted, so idk

Answer (score 0):

If you may use a `List<string[]>` you do not have to worry about the array length.
In the following example, the variable `lines` will be a list arrays, like:

["500000", "0.005", "6000"]

["690000", "0.003", "5200"]

```
static void ReadFromFile(string filePath)
{
    try
    {
        // Create an instance of StreamReader to read from a file.
        // The using statement also closes the StreamReader.
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            List<string[]> lines = new List<string[]>();
            string line;
            // Read and display lines from the file until the end of 
            // the file is reached.
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                string[] splittedLine = line.Split(',');
                lines.Add(splittedLine);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // Let the user know what went wrong.
        Console.WriteLine("The file could not be read:");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately i am unable to use lists.

Comment: @praiseodin - Where does it say that in your question?

Answer (score 0):

While other have split method, I will have a more "scolar"-"specified" method.
You have some Csv value in a file. Find a name for this object stored in a Csv, name every column, type them.
Define the default value of those field. Define what happends for missing column, and malformed field. Header?

Now that you know what you have, define what you want. This time again: Object name -> Property -> Type.

Believe me or not, the simple definition of your input and output solved your issue.
Use [CsvHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/) to simplify your code.

CSV File Definition:

```
public class CsvItem_WithARealName
{
    public int data1;
    public decimal data2;
    public int goodVariableNames;
}

public class CsvItemMapper : ClassMap<CsvItem_WithARealName>
{
    public CsvItemMapper()
    {   //mapping based on index. cause file has no header.
        Map(m => m.data1).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.data2).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.goodVariableNames).Index(2);
    }
}
```

A Csv reader method, point a document it will give your the Csv Item.
Here we have some configuration: no header and InvariantCulture for decimal convertion

```
private IEnumerable<CsvItem_WithARealName> GetCsvItems(string filePath)
{
    using (var fileReader = File.OpenText(filePath))
    using (var csvReader = new CsvHelper.CsvReader(fileReader))
    {
        csvReader.Configuration.CultureInfo = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
        csvReader.Configuration.HasHeaderRecord = false;
        csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<CsvItemMapper>();
        while (csvReader.Read())
        {
            var record = csvReader.GetRecord<CsvItem_WithARealName>();
            yield return record;
        }
    }
}
```

Usage :

```
var filename = "csvExemple.txt";
var items = GetCsvItems(filename);
```